# How do i import python modules using Jython in java application (using Eclipse)?

Tags: java, jython-2.7

I am a Jython beginner, facing a problem while trying to use python modules in java.

The python file is in proper folder wrt the java file as the print statement works when file is called from java. However, when used `PythonInterpreter.execfile("fileName.py")` which imports python built-in modules or `PythonInterpreter.exec("from numpy import numpy as np");` in java, it gives following error:

> File "<string>", line 1, in 
> ImportError: No module named numpy

And using  `python.exec("import fileName"); PyObject func = python.get("fileName").__getattr__("defined_function"); System.out.println(func.__call__().__tojava__(String.class));` gives the error:

> File "__pyclasspath__/fileName.py", line 8, in defined_function
> ImportError: No module named numpy

Again, defined_function imports multiple built-in modules, including Numpy.

The __pyclasspath__ has some information [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130227204152/https://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixB.html#working-with-classpath), but for `.jar` files and nothing about why is it prepended with `.py` file-path in the error specification.

The pyDev python interpreter used in Eclipse has NumPy installed. Windows>Preferences>PyDev>Python interpreter looks like: [interpreter window of eclipse showing Numpy present as a package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wllph.png)

I hope the question is clear, please comment if you'd like any specifics.

Comment: What does `os.path` Look like ?

Comment: @codeflush.dev how do i find that? is it the global path of my python file?

Comment: C:\Users\username\Documents\folder1\cloudsim-3.0.3\examples has fileName.py and cloudsim-3.0.3 is my eclipse project folder

Comment: that is the lookup path for modules. Numpy should be installed there. You can also and more locations to `os.path`

Comment: This is the path when i searched for numpy.py in system : C:\Users\user\anaconda3\pkgs\distributed-2.11.0-py37_0\Lib\site-packages\distributed\protocol And os.path is: C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\ntpath.py